# How do I unit test model validation in controllers decorated with [ApiController]?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

As pointed out in [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51545439/1621861) to [Asp.Net Core 2.1 ApiController does not automatically validate model under unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543863/asp-net-core-2-1-apicontroller-does-not-automatically-validate-model-under-unit), the automatic ModelState validation that ASP.NET Core 2.1's ApiControllerAttribute gives us only works when actualyy requestion the action at runtime, not by calling it with an invalid parameter in a unit test.

However, I still want to test if my action actually returns a BadRequestResult when supplying an incorrect model. Is there any way of doing this? I get that I can still manually check if ModelState.IsValid is false, and returning BadRequest() myself, but that kind of defeats the point of the automatic validation.

Am I stuck manually checking ModelState.IsValid after all, or is there a way to make use of the new ApiControllerAttribute model validation in a unit test?

Comment: I ended up making an AspNetCore middleware that tests if the model is invalid, and if so, return a badrequest in that.  Unfortunately to do that also means you can only test that the validator is working via an integration test.

Comment: I figured I could just have the unit test check wether the controller is decorated with ApiController... It feels wrong but in the end it might be better than no test at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to validate that the api's are returning a badrequest when the data annotations are broken then you need to do an api integration test.
One nice option is to run the integration tests via an in-memory client using the [TestServer](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/testserver.aspx)

Here's an example:

```
//arrange
var b = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<YourMainApplication.Startup>()
    .UseEnvironment("development");

var server = new TestServer(b) { BaseAddress = new Uri(url) };
var client = server.CreateClient();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourInvalidModel);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

//act
var result = await client.PostAsync("api/yourController", content);

//assert
Assert.AreEqual(400, (int)result.StatusCode);
```

If you only need to make sure that the annotations is proper setup you can manually trigger the validation via the [TryValidateObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject?view=netcore-2.1) method

```
var obj = new YourClass();
var context = new ValidationContext(obj);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
var valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, context, results, true);
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. One question: My startup class declares a service in which I wrapped all database access. In a unit test, I have a mock Service that just sets and gets some test values that I check. Is there a way of having Startup use that mock service when doing the integration test?

Comment: @Bas You can call `.ConfigureTestServices()` on the web host builder to configure services to be used while integration testing. That way, you can also replace existing registrations.

Comment: The issue with `TryValidateObject` is that it doesn't drill down into child objects.  Somehow, asp DOES do this missing bit of functionality, but it doesn't appear to be exposed.